# object reference not set to an instance of an object in dll

Tags: c#, windows, dll

i wrote this method in my application and it works fine. i decided to create a DLL file for it.
But the same method give me the error **object reference not set to an instance of an object in dll**.
the code is

```
public void Try(string conStr, string storedProcedure)
    {

        try
        {

            //create a connection string
            sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            // create command
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, sqlCon);

            //add command type
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // add the stored procedure name
            sqlCmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;

            //Open connection
            sqlCon.Open();

            // Execute transaction
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close connection
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
```

The error ocuurs at :

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, sqlCon);
```

What can be the problem ??

Comment: Its because your `sqlCmd` is null, and you are trying to use it in creating its own instance. At that line you are creating a new instance of SqlCommand and you are accessing its `CommandText` before creating its object.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling SQL command before setting its correspondent value, you should set the value of CommandText and then instantiate SQL command

Comment: i fixed the problem,but i want to know why i cant use the same code in the dll file and i need to to pass the command text a the stage of initialization: sqlcmd = new sqlcommand(storedprocedure, sqlcon)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created the instance of `sqlCmd` and you trying to pass its `CommandText` to the process that creates that object. You seem to be passing the stored procedure as a parameter to execute so try  something like:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlCon);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try to keep your connection open for the shortest time possible. I would advise to use a *using* statement.

```
public void Try(string conStr, string storedProcedure) {
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr)) {
        // create command, also a local variable
        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        // set connection
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon

        //add command type
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // add the stored procedure name
        sqlCmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;

        //Open connection
        sqlCon.Open();

        // Execute transaction
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok @Maarten,try and come back to you.